# Why does toggling of a tag stops working?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#fantasy_login_img').click(function () {
   $('#unamelogin').focusin();
   $('#fblogin').toggle('slow').animate(1000);
   $('#gplogin').toggle('slow').animate(1000);
   $('#fantasyLogin').toggle('slow').animate(1000);
});
```

I have this code, when I am pressing it smoothly its working fine but when I am clicks it fast manny times it stops working.

what can be the reason?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for this

Comment: the delay is because `.animate(1000)` try to remove `.animate(1000)` and test it again

Comment: is it bcoz of the animation delay but why does it stops working  it should not show it lately

Comment: You need [**stops**](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 3):

try to add .stop() before every toggle like this

```
$('#fantasy_login_img').click(function () {
$('#unamelogin').focusin();
$('#fblogin').stop().toggle('slow').animate(1000);
$('#gplogin').stop().toggle('slow').animate(1000);
$('#fantasyLogin').stop().toggle('slow').animate(1000);
});
```